# Form Class or Controller in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

How would I go about creating the following:

I am looking to create a dropdown menu full of form input types but when one is selected I would like it to create the respective html for the input and save it to the database. I will be using codeigniter.

**Example:**

If I select Text Area from the dropdown menu it will then create `<textarea></textarea>` so then I could escape it and save it to the database.

I have come up with the following code so far

```
        if (isset($_REQUEST['general_options'])) 
        {

            $optionName  = $_REQUEST['general_options'];

            $optionValue = strtolower(str_replace(" ", "", $_REQUEST['general_options']));


            //$this->load->view( $page, $data, FALSE);
            echo form_label($optionName, $optionValue);
            echo form_input($optionValue, '', '');
        }`
```

`

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Creating a form input dependent on the type selected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835223/php-creating-a-form-input-dependent-on-the-type-selected)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your intent on reloading the page every time you make a select choice, your best bet is to incorporate something like jQuery which is a javascript library.

Then with that you can do something like

```
<select id="mySelect">
   <option value="none" selected="selected">---Select---</option>
   <option value="textarea">Textarea</option>
</select>

<div id="appendElem"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#mySelect').change(function()
   {
      if($(this+' option:selected').val() == "textarea")
      {
          $('#appendElem').html('<textarea>Some Text...</textarea>');
      }
   })
</script>
```

A note worth mentioning is just cause Codeigniter has a form helper class, and makes it sound through its docs that its the only way to build a form on your page. Standard HTML forms work just as well in your views.

Comment: That could be an idea but I was wanting to save it in the admin so I could load it in the front end

Comment: What does saving the data from the inputs or whatever have to do with a form in your admin? Cause you can save whatever in your database and have it load to your uses however your wanting it to this way as well, as this has no effect over how you store whatever or display it to your end user